# I don't know how it works Import Table

Tags: reverse-engineering

Can someone explain me the Import Table and Import Address table? I'm not understanding anything. What's OriginalThunk and FirstThunk? And How does it works the Import Adress Table. Thank :)

Comment: Please expand your question. What language are you using? What documentation have you consulted? Post any example code you are working with. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've consulted the PE Documentation of Microsoft. I use C++ Language.